# How can I rotate a font icon 45 degrees?

Tags: css, rotation, icons, icon-fonts

I want to rotate this font icon 45 degrees. The icon has this CSS (all CSS compiled via LESS):

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before, [class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

And it's this Flaticon: http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/hand-pointer_70655

I've installed it as an icon font.

However, when I try to rotate it 45 degrees, so that the finger points to the top right corner, it doesn't work. I'm trying by installing the icon like so:

```
<i class="flaticon-hand-10 gly-rotate-45"></i>
```

Where this is the class `gly-rotate-45`:

```
.gly-rotate-45 {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.5);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

The browser is picking up `transform: rotate(45deg);`, but the icon isn't rotated. How can I rotate this icon font?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The reason why the icon does not rotate in it's 'raw' state is because it's default `display` setting is `inline`.

You cannot apply transforms to inline elements like this.

To solve the problem just apply `display:inline-block".

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Flaticon';
  src: url('data:font/ttf;base64,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') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.flaticon-hand-10:before {
  content: "\e000";
}
.gly-rotate-45 {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.5);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<i class="flaticon-hand-10 gly-rotate-45"></i>
```

Answer (score 5):

## Problem

The content (i.e. the icon) is being added by the CSS and can't be rotated on its own. (I'm trying to find the exact reason why, but I'm having trouble identifying if it's browser specific or not.)

## Solution

Encapsulate the element in another element and rotate that one. You'll also need to set size boundaries otherwise it could have drastic results that you don't want.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Flaticon';
  src: url('data:font/ttf;base64,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') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.flaticon-hand-10:before {
  content: "\e000";
}
.gly-rotate-45 {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.5);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
p {
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p class="gly-rotate-45">
  <i class="flaticon-hand-10"></i>
</p>
```

For now, that's my solution, but it feels clunky and I will continue to investigate a better answer.